# How to redirect to a URL in JavaScript after submitting a certain keyword in a form?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I am creating a website and I am creating a form in it. In this form, I wanted to make it redirect to a URL (www.google.pt, for example) only if a keyword is written in the form when submitted (for example, "google"). Can anyone help me please? Here is the HTML code I've written to create the form:

```
<form action="/action_page.php" method="post">
  <input type="text">
  <br><br>
  <button type="submit">SUBMETER</button>
</form>
```

Comment: No, my question requires a keyword to redirect to another webpage.

Comment: So, on this site we expect people to actually try and solve their issue before posting a question. See [ask], especially the part "Search, and research". You lucked out and got Cory to answer your question for free.

Comment: Yea, I just like solving problems. Or maybe I like the abuse...

Answer (score 0):

```
$(form).submit(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    if($(input).val().indexOf('yourWord') !== -1){
        window.location = 'http://www.google.pt';
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I tried but it didn't work...

Comment: It's going to require some editing. This is just a template to do what you're asking.